# Connect to service in Traefik based on HostSNI with gRPC

Tags: java, grpc, traefik, grpc-java

I want to have 1 entrypoint in Traefik, and then two different routers that routes based on HostSNI. I don't really know how I can access these different services based on the HostSNI

My entrypoint is `:5160`.

Two different routers that goes to two different services.
One has the rule `HostSNI('service-1.local')`, the other one has the rule `HostSNI('service-2.local')`.

How can I with gRPC in Java connect to these services?

My client so far:

```java
public class GrpcClient {
     public GrpcClient(String host, int port) {
        this(ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext());
    }

    public GrpcClient(ManagedChannelBuilder<?> channelBuilder) {
        channel = channelBuilder.build();
        blockingStub = ServiceGPRC.newBlockingStub(channel);
        asyncStub = ServiceGRPC.newStub(channel);
    }
    public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
        channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: check this guide: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/grpc/

Answer (score 1):

SNI is a TLS extension so requires use of TLS. Also see https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#rule_1 .

In your GrpcClient you then cannot use plaintext but have to use a TLS channel. See the example https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/example-tls. The SNI is set up from the authority which you can override with ManagedChannelBuilder#overrideAuthority.